# Transfer data from SQL Server to MySQL

Tags: c#, mysql, load-data-infile

I need to transfer around 2m records from 4 tables in SQL Server 2008 Express to MySQL.

In C# I can insert these records very quickly within a transaction with the [Table-Valued parameter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb675163.aspx). (Around 50 seconds).

How can I do something similar for MySQL in C#?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Read the explanations in the [MySQL Reference Manual](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/insert-speed.html). The best you can do is use `LOAD DATA INFILE` while disabling indices before and recreating (and thus batch-calculating them) afterwards. There is more interesting advice if that doesn't work out for you.

Comment: I'm curious in what the other more interesting advice is :)

Comment: @Gerbrand: Sorry to disappoint you, but I meant "in the article."

Answer (score 0):

Are you locked into using C# for the migration? If you're not and only want to transfer the data you can use the [MySQL Migration Toolkit](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/migration-toolkit/en/index.html) to do the transfer for you.

Comment: I'm locked into using c# and I need only to transfer the data